# Code to stop a youtube video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I have some youtube videos on a page and have used CSS to display the selected video and to cycle to other videos, basically using hidden and block elements to hide and display each video. I am trying to avoid the use of jQuery as I have not found a suitable source code nor have the experience to edit an existing one to meet my needs. The problem is because I am hiding and showing the videos, if I play one video and move to the next - well the original video is still playing, thus you get audio crossover, and with many videos will get a slowdown of the PC. Youtube videos can be paused with the "k" keyboard stroke, so I added an "accesskey" function to the links to pause it. However I guess the browser is hiding it before the accesskey is activate and thus the video continues to play in the background, as the accesskey only works with an active video playing. Any suggestions or advice to solve my issue.

**The website (live example):**
http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/resources.php

**HTML:**

```
<script>
function show(id) {
    var item = document.getElementById(id);
    var all  = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
    for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++)all[i].style.display = 'none';
    if(item)item.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<h1>Practice Techniques</h1>              

<div class="resourcecontainer">
    <a href="javascript:show('test2');">
    <img class="resourceimage" src="images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="resourcecontainer">
    <a href="javascript:show('test3');">
    <img class="resourceimage" src="images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="resourcecontainer">
    <a href="javascript:show('test4');">
    <img class="resourceimage" src="images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="resourcecontainer">
    <a href="javascript:show('test5');">
    <img class="resourceimage" src="images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0">
    </a>
</div>

<br><br>

<h1>Equipment Selection</h1>              

<div class="resourcecontainer"><img class="resourceimage" src="images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0"></div>
<div class="resourcecontainer"><img class="resourceimage" src="images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0"></div>
<div class="resourcecontainer"><img class="resourceimage" src="images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0"></div>
<div class="resourcecontainer"><img class="resourceimage" src="images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0"></div>

<br><br>

<div id="test1" class="hidden">

</div>
<div id="test2" class="hidden">
    <div class="resourcevideo">
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test1');">(Previous)</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test1');" accesskey="k">[Close]</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test3');">(Next)</a></div>
        <iframe class="centervideo" width="550" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EO4-B_ttHe0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test3" class="hidden">
    <div class="resourcevideo">
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test2');">(Previous)</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test1');" accesskey="k">[Close]</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test4');">(Next)</a></div>
        <iframe class="centervideo" width="550" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XiGt0X0csoE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test4" class="hidden">
    <div class="resourcevideo">
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test3');">(Previous)</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test1');">[Close]</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test5');">(Next)</a></div>
        <iframe class="centervideo" width="550" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XnbPGKB34bU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test5" class="hidden">
    <div class="resourcevideo">
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test4');">(Previous)</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test1');">[Close]</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a href="javascript:show('test2');">(Next)</a></div>
        <iframe class="centervideo" width="550" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qiZOkhJ_wnY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.resourcecontainer {
    width:210px;
    height:140px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.resourceimage {
    border:solid 1px;
    border-color:#A5A5A5;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

.resourcevideo {
    clear: both;
    width: 600px;
    height: 450px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-top: -210px;
}

.centervideo {
    margin: 25px;
}

.videolink {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#AA3537;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: block;
}

.videolink a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.videolink a:hover {
    color:#000000;
}

.hidden { 
    display:none; 
}

#test1 { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: You can use [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Queueing_Functions) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) and its functions, and instead of showing and hiding videos dynamically load youtube video one at a time in a single div element. This way your next/previous video will only start once the current video stops playing.

Your show() function should be like this-

```
function show(id,current_video,next_video,previous_video) {
    var item = document.getElementById(id);
    var all  = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
    for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++)all[i].style.display = 'none';
    if(item)item.style.display = 'block';

    $("#prev").attr('href','javascript:show("test2","'+next_video+'","'+previous_video+'","'+current_video+'")');
    $("#next").attr('href','javascript:show("test2","'+previous_video+'","'+current_video+'","'+next_video+'")');

    $("#player").attr('src',"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+current_video+'?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://localhost');
    $("#player")[0].src += "&autoplay=0";

}
```

This show function will now dynamically change your next/prev and current video.

Youtube Player API should be used like this

```
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
//document.getElementById("video").hide();
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;

//setInterval(checkTime,1000);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
  height: '350',
  width: '550',
  videoId: 'EO4-B_ttHe0',
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
}
//setInterval(checkTime,1000);
// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
//event.target.playVideo();
}
// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
/*if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
    player.seekTo(0);
    stopVideo();

}*/
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {

  done = true;
}
}
function stopVideo() {
player.stopVideo();
}
```

and your HTML should be like this

```
<h1>Practice Techniques</h1>              

<div class="resourcecontainer">
    <a href="javascript:show('test2','EO4-B_ttHe0','XiGt0X0csoE','qiZOkhJ_wnY');">
    <img class="resourceimage" src="http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="resourcecontainer">
   <a href="javascript:show('test2','XiGt0X0csoE','XnbPGKB34bU','EO4-B_ttHe0');">
    <img class="resourceimage" src="http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="resourcecontainer">
    <a href="javascript:show('test2','XnbPGKB34bU','qiZOkhJ_wnY','XiGt0X0csoE');">
    <img class="resourceimage" src="http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="resourcecontainer">
   <a href="javascript:show('test2','qiZOkhJ_wnY','EO4-B_ttHe0','XnbPGKB34bU');">
    <img class="resourceimage" src="http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0">
    </a>
</div>

<br><br>

<h1>Equipment Selection</h1>              

<div class="resourcecontainer"><img class="resourceimage" src="http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0"></div>
<div class="resourcecontainer"><img class="resourceimage" src="http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0"></div>
<div class="resourcecontainer"><img class="resourceimage" src="http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0"></div>
<div class="resourcecontainer"><img class="resourceimage" src="http://s187242710.onlinehome.us/tdsa/images/sampleresource.jpg" width="190" height="120" border="0"></div>

<br><br>




<div id="test1" class="hidden">

</div>
<div id="test2" class="hidden">
    <div class="resourcevideo">
        <div class="videolink"><a id="prev" href="javascript:show('test1');">(Previous)</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a id="current" href="javascript:show('test1');" accesskey="k">[Close]</a></div>
        <div class="videolink"><a id="next" href="javascript:show('test3');">(Next)</a></div>
        <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Complete code can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/shoaibakhter/xz7tfs2d/8/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the 'src' attribute of the iframe (and store it in 'data-src'). To play again, reverse the procedure. To stop them all at once, do something like this:

```
$('.center-video').each( function () {
  $(this).attr('data-src',$(this).attr('src'));
  $(this).attr('src','');
});
```

Ps. You need to set the video to autoplay and using it to play does not work on iOS (as autoplay does not work there).